# Only can type letters in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

In my VS2008, suddenly, I can use just letters, no enter, space, delete, backspace, or any other keys.
Any advice how to fix this?
Keyboard is working perfectly in other applications.
Thanks.

Comment: I get this sometimes... try alt+Enter.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vseditor/archive/2005/05/12/417011.aspx?Redirected=true

Comment: "The good news is that we have identified a fix for the issue, we know how to prevent it and how to get out of the state when it happens." - back in 2005 :)

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but ... did you try just restarting Visual Studio?

Comment: i currently have the same problem constantly in VS2012, can you tell me which extensions and add-ins you got installed when the issue first came up?

Comment: Old thread but I fixed my error not by Scroll Lock (which promoted me to look at those keys but the 'function' button that the Microsoft keyboard I have uses.)

Comment: in VS 2017, i still have this problem

Answer (score 19):

I was having this problem several times a day.  Make sure the Language setting is set to "Same as Microsoft Windows" under Tools -> Options -> Environment.

Comment: This worked for me and a restart of VS; this time, VS 2019 community version.

Comment: In VS 2019: Tools -> Options -> Environment -> International Settings.

Answer (score 12):

ReSharper `Options - Environment - General - Clear Caches` solved problem.

Answer (score 5):

Close the document that you are working on and reopen it.  It works for me when my keyboard seems to be not functioning and i can't type into the current form.

Answer (score 3):

For me the only thing that worked is this solution in this link => https://superuser.com/a/1626086/1055404

Just go to tools -> options -> Environment -> Keyboard and click on reset button on the top right corner

Answer (score 1):

Try to remember line number (better ;) ), close the file you want to modify, then re open it.

It happening sometimes to me and that "hack" works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It is realy strange behaviour, in my case even the restart of windows was not helpful. the trick was for me to open the project using "File" menu in VS and then open the .csproj not 
.sln file.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling Productivity Power Tools and restarting the IDE worked for me.

Should not that it was very shortly after installing Resharper that the problem occurred, having never experienced it before.

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me when I'm close to run out of RAM. Closing processes (not VS) makes keyboard usable again.

Answer (score 0):

I work under a Virtual Machine, On my case I had to close and open the VS again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you been comparing changes before a push/commit? Check if you have any modal windows open. Had the same problem and when I tried to close VS17, it warned me, that I had a modal window that prevented some user inputs. I pressed "ok" to the window, restarted VS and I could again do inputs. I had the exact same error as you - could insert letters, but couldnt fx delete, "end", "home" etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Visual Studio 2017. I was not able to remove code after typing. I just close the Visual Studio and run as administrator. Its working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Set another keyword mapping scheme in the
**Tools** - **Options** - **Environment** - **Keyboard**

Answer (score 0):

Look at your keyboard shortcuts and make sure there isn't anything set to any of the keys you're trying to use. This happened with me when I installed an extension and messed with some keyboard shortcuts and inadvertently set settings sync to 'c' no matter where it was input.

Answer (score 0):

For me updating VS did the trick

Answer (score -2):

Close vertical or horizontal group.