# In Visual Studio 2012 - Keyboard suddenly stops working properly

Tags: visual-studio-2012, stylecop

as stated in the questions title, we have an issue with VS2012. The problem is that sometimes suddenly some keyboard-input in VS isn't executed properly, if at all.

When the problem occurs, we are only able to type in characters and numbers, but neither are we able to delete them (backspace or DEL), nor to use the arrow key to jump up down a line or to the next/previous character. Overwriting a text which has been marked with the mouse is working.

I have found a very similar [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830058/visual-studio-keyboard-doesnt-work#comment26899782_10830058) but the hints stated there doesn't work here. Those are:

1. Hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. Closing and Reopening Editor Windows
3. Closing the ToolboxWindow
4. Restarting VS
5. Pressing ScollLock

The Problem seems to be related to the Stylecop-AddIn. After uninstalling it, the issue doesn't come up anymore. Is there some known workaround? Thanks in advance!

Comment: StyleCop uses Resharper, could your version of R# be out of date?  Also could your version of StyleCop be out of date?  Maybe one of these has fixed your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but: how could that be? I mean Stylecop is able to run without R#. I am using R# V7.1.3. It sure isn't the latest version but since i would have to pay for the upgrade i hoped that there was some solution other than upgrading..

Answer (score 0):

Apparently StyleCop can be used with out Resharper, I didn't know.  Very sorry.  However, if you look at the documentation for StyleCop, if you right click on your project, click Source Analysis Settings, you will be presented with a dialog to turn on or off all of StyleCops rules.

Here is a link to the actual documentation which has images which helps describe it.  [StyleCop Settings](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Managing%20StyleCop%20Project%20Settings&referringTitle=Documentation)