# visual studio 2015 stops responding when i type a charecter

Tags: visual-studio-2015

When I go to type a character in my project visual studio 2015 stops responding and eventually I have to close it with task manager. Ive tried debugging it with new instance of visual studio I just cant seem to find the problem. also have even tried closing all other programs but it still freezes up. Does any one know what the problem is?

Comment: Where's the program you executed? May be a case of infinite loop.

Comment: no its not because of the project even with a empty project as soon as i start typing visual studio gets hung up.

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/641783/visual-studio-stops-responding-to-keyboard-input

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830058/visual-studio-keyboard-doesnt-work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2010: Editor stops responding to keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310033/visual-studio-2010-editor-stops-responding-to-keyboard)

Comment: There are many existing posts regarding the same issue. Please Google to find similar posts on SO and other sites or check out the related section on this post's page. :)